# Ubuntu 13.10 - how can i install package?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, package-management, update-manager

How to fix this problem? Everytime i am trying to install/update packages it fails

```
root@nson:~# sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dconf-editor
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 230 not upgraded.
Need to get 99,4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 492 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe dconf-editor amd64 0.16.1-1
  Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/d-conf/dconf-editor_0.16.1-1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@nson:~# 

root@nson:~# sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to be.archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to extras.ubuntu.com]
```

Comment: Try changing your download server..you can try selecting the main server.

Comment: How please show in answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Check that did you have an working internet connection.And also select Best server for downloading packages from software and updates.

Then update the repositories and try to install packages,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

Comment: But its giving me above errors see my Question please?

Comment: I'm answered for the above errors.

Comment: when i do apt-get update and apt-get install package name it fails with error to connect. But how do you change to main server package and how do you change the primary dns, secondary dns so that apt-get do not get fail.

Comment: Did you able to choose best server from software and updates?

Answer (score 1):

Open up your Software Center by going to the dash and searching for it.
In the menu, select "edit"->"software sources".

In the pop-up window that opens, there will be a 'Ubuntu software' tab (the first one) and a 'Download from select option'. Choose 'Main server' and enter your password.

Then try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in terminal.

[image]

Comment: Its in a remote location where i have only SSH access, how do you do that Main Server selection via command line please?

Comment: @YumYumYum Take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)